# realpath(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, directadmin

everyone. I get this error on my shared host. I contact the support and they said that they don't give permission for my account to open_basedir area. (Since it is not an upgraded account) What can I do unless buy for premium version.

Comment: dont use realpath then. I dont know what type of answer you're expecting to get  ?

Comment: where do you get this error?

Answer (score 1):

try use

```
\URL::to("your path");
or in blade files
{{url("your path")}}
```